# Is there any weight for a retweet by a bot?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, twitter

There are many bots in Twitter that keep retweeting certain hash tags. Retweets carry weight in terms of SEO.

Is it the same with a Twitter bot ? A bot could be written for the sake of tweet collection. If someone wants to track everything regarding `#MalaysianPlaneMystery`, the bot could help. But does those re tweets carry enough weight ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the premise of your question is arguable. I dont think retweets (or tweets) automatically count for 'seo', though I appreciate that would depend on your definition of seo.

See this video here " Are facebook and twitter signals part of the ranking algorithm?'

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udqtSM-6QbQ